# Asian sci-fi movie from early 2000's with two girls fighting on a rooftop?

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

So, I remember watching on YouTube a movie scene of two asian girls fighting on a random rooftop. One of them uses a enormous piece of wood to attack, and both of them start to use things to hit each other. They both have short hair and wear opposite colors, from what I can remember.

Why do I think it's a sci-fi movie: The action in this scene is pretty exaggerated, one of them is probably not "human" and I think I saw other scenes of scary creatures appearing in the same movie. I don't want to go with stereotypes and say that japanese films are really over the top when it comes to these type of scenes, cause I have a feeling that this happened in a pretty weird movie already.

I just contacted a friend who I believed saw the same scene with me when we were kids and he said something like "oh, that chinese vampire movie?". And something clicked.
I do remember a white guy with blonde hair that was pretty scary and may be a vampire for what he said. But I am a hundred percent sure that the rest of the cast is asian. He was certain that the movie is chinese and I woudn't doubt cause he is obsessed with chinese martial arts since then. He also added that the girls were fighting over a teddy bear or something and the fight was pretty funny (I remember it being really intense though). I tried a lot to make him remember something else, but that's all we got.

None of us has find the original movie and we both are even more curious now.

Comment: By the way, I was a kid when I first saw it and I thought it was amazing. Went to local video stores looking for the full movie but never found it. I basically watched half of it using YouTube and some old video sites that don't exist anymore.

Comment: I assume the movie was in (Japanese?) If not, was it in English? Dubbed? or Subtitled?

Comment: @NJohnny Good question, I'm brazilian and it was dubbed in Portuguese. So I don't really know the nationality.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does that movie also have a guy who uses a "head puller" to decapitate people? I think not, but somehow your short description reminded me of a different movie.

Comment: I contacted a friend about this movie and got some new info. I edited the post!

Comment: @Clockwork I really can't confirm or deny. Maybe there's some scene that I didn't get to see with a head puller or somthing alike.

Comment: "chinese martian arts" - due to the scifi context, I am not 100% you did not mean what you wrote, but if you did mean to write "martial arts", please fix that typo.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm so sorry, I fixed it. Didn't mean to write that. Sorry;

Comment: @fisheye: No worries, I found it quite funny actually ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [The Twins Effect](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0351887/) from 2003.

> It's a high-kicking battle on the dark side when an ace vampire slayer and his beautiful sidekicks wage the ultimate martial-arts showdown with one of the most dangerous of the undead.

Starring pop duo the [Twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twins_(group)) & co-starring Jackie Chan. You can see the scene you're looking for below at 1:20:

Comment: Wow, I am a Jackie Chan fan and have seen lots of his movies, but never saw that one. And the scene OP described does seen to fit. ;) I'm going to have to try to track down a copy.

Comment: Ok, looks like Jackie Chan only has a cameo roll (Ambulance Driver) which is probably why I had not heard of the movie.

Comment: Yeah, 'co-starring' might've been a bit of an overstatement. ;) But at least you can see him singing the theme song in a featurette (plus his son appears in the sequel)!

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! Yes! This movie. I feel like I just had the best trip of nostalgia of my life. It's weird that the white dude in the movie still creeps me. This fight is AMAZING, and yes, it is over the top, so I'm sorry if I was misleading. Can't wait to watch it completely for the first time (and there's a sequel too). Thank you again, my man!